# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, valueerror

I've been trying to write a Python file to scrape the whole content of a page of a website. Now, everything seems to be fine in my code, until I run it.

I've made sure to link the items from the items python file. I shouldn't get any errors, but yet I keep getting "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

**Here is my code from my main python file:**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AnalogicScrapeItem


class AnalogicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'analogic'
    start_urls = ['https://www.analogic.com/about/']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AnalogicScrapeItem()
        body1 = response.css('body').css('::text').extract()

        items['body1'] = body1

        yield items
```

**Here is my code from items.py file:**

```
import scrapy


class AnalogicScrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    body1 = scrapy.Field()
```

**After running the code, here is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kev/PycharmProjects/whole_page_extract3/analogic_scrape/
        analogic_scrape/spiders/analogic.py", line 3, in <module> 
        from ..items import AnalogicScrapeItem
        ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
from analogic_scrape.items import AnalogicScrapeItem
```

would do the job. When you use `..`, you are importing files from a relative path.

However, if you run the script from command line with `scrapy crawl analogic`, relative imports are not a problem.

Comment: sry the class from items.py file is AnalogicScrapeItem, not AnalogicItem. I made a mistake.. Does that change anything other than the import part?

Comment: Ok then import that class name. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help my friend!

Comment: No problem, you can accept it as an answer and upvote. :)